# How to update page when data is changed in nextjs?

Tags: next.js

When I delete one of the notes, it deletes from the DB. And to see the effect, I need to reload the page every time I delete a note.

How do I see the not deleted notes without reloading the page?

Here's the code for my page:

```
export default function Home(notes) {
  const [notesData, setNotesData] = useState(notes);

  const deleteNote = async (note) => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/${note}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Notes:</h1>
      {notesData.notes.map((note) => {
        return (
          <div className="flex">
            <p>{note.title}</p>
            <p onClick={() => deleteNote(note.title)}>Delete</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api`);
  const { data } = await res.json();

  return { props: { notes: data } };
}
```

Comment: Make a request to fetch the updated data and update the `notesData` state variable. That will trigger a re-render with the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fetching the data with `getServerSideProps` you need to recall that in order to get the updated data like this :

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const router = useRouter()

const refreshData = () => router.replace(router.asPath);
```

But also you can store the data from `getServerSideProps` in a state and render that state and trigger a state update after a note is deleted like this :

```
export default function Home(notes) {
  const [notesData, setNotesData] = useState(notes);

  const deleteNote = async (note) => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/${note}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Notes:</h1>
      {notesData.notes.map((note) => {
        return (
          <div className="flex">
            <p>{note.title}</p>
            <p onClick={() => deleteNote(note.title).then(()=>{
                const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api`);
                const { data } = await res.json();
                setNotesData(data)
             })
            }>Delete</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api`);
  const { data } = await res.json();

  return { props: { notes: data } };
}
```